# What is the best way to realize this database

Tags: database, zend-framework

I have to realize a system with different kind of users and I think to realize it in this way:

- A user table with only id, email and password.
- Two different tables correlated to the user table in a 1-to-1 relation. Each table define specific attributes of each kind of user.

Is this the best way to realize it? I should use the InnoDB storage engine?

If I realize it in this way, how can I handle the tables in the Zend Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the second part of your question but the pattern you describe is called super and subtype in datamodelling. If this is the right choice can't be answered without knowing more about the differences between these user types and how they will be used in the application. There are different approaches when converting logical super/subtypes into physical tables.

Here are some relevant links:
http://www.sqlmag.com/article/data-modeling/implementing-supertypes-and-subtypes
and the next one about pitfalls and (mis)use of subtyping
http://www.ocgworld.com/doc/OCG_Subtyping_Techniques.pdf

In general I am, from a pragmatic point of view, very reluctant to follow your choice and most often opt to create one table containing all columns. In most cases there are a number of places where the application needs show all users in some sort of listing with specific columns for specific types (and empty if not applicable for that type). It quickly leads to non-straigtforward queries and all sort of extra code to deal with the different tables that it's just not worth being 'conceptually correct'.

Two reasons for me to still split the subtypes into different tables are if the subtypes are so truly different that it makes no logical sense to have them in one table and if the number of rows is so enormous that the overhead of the 'unneeded' columns when putting it all in one table actually starts to matter

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I am not interested in performance, but only in the possibility to easy enlarge the project in future? Is this the best solution or it's the same of choosing the super-and-sub-types datamodelling?

Comment: My advice: If you can't come up with a very good reason why you can't have all users with all columns in one table don't split into multiple tables

Comment: Well, I don't dislike this option, but on your experience is it easily enlargeable in future? How can I define different type of users? With an ENUM column? I really thank you for the answer. PS: you seem very expert. Can I have your Skype ID?

Answer (score 0):

On php side you can use Doctrine 2 ORM. It's easy to integrate with zf, and you could easily implement this table structure as inheritance in your doctrine mapping.